# Counting number of characters in a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, count

For homework I have been set the following:

Build a dictionary with the names from myEmployees list as
keys and assign each employee a salary of 10 000 (as value). Loop over the dictionary
and increase the salary of employees which names have more than four
letters with 1000 * length of their name. Print the dictionary contents before
and after the increase.

I can't figure out how to do it.

This is what I've come up with so far.

```
employeeDict = {"John":'10,000', "Daren":"10,000", "Graham":"10,000", "Steve":"10,000", "Adren":"10,000"}

say = 'Before increase'
print say
print employeeDict

say1 = 'After increase'
print say1

for x in employeeDict:
x = len(employeeDict)
if x > 5:
    print employeeDict[x]
```

Comment: Your dictionary values are better off as numeric types instead of strings

Comment: Fix your indentation first. `x = len(employeeDict)
if x > 5:
    print employeeDict[x]` should be indented .

Comment: An employee's name is a string, and there is a function called `len` that gives you the length of a string or a list (or a dict or a set or a tuple or...)

Comment: The homework says "more than four character". Why are you using `>5` instead of `>4`?

Answer (score 0):

You have some indentation problems, clearly, but the main problems are that you are taking the length of the dictionary (getting the number of keys) not taking the length of the key. You also have some bad logic.

```
employeeDict = {"John":'10,000', "Daren":"10,000", "Graham":"10,000", "Steve":"10,000", "Adren":"10,000"}

say = 'Before increase'
print say
print employeeDict

say1 = 'After increase'
print say1

for x in employeeDict:
    length = len(employeeDict)  # <---- indent this
    if length >= 5:    # <--- greater than 4
        # convert string to number, add money, convert back to string
        employeeDict[x] = str(int(employeeDict[x]) + 1000 * (length))

print employeeDict[x]
```

Comment: Would it not be a better idea to simply make his key values integers?

Comment: It certainly would. I was just working with the setup that was given.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the values to integers/floats.

```
employeeDict = {"John":10000, "Daren":10000, "Graham":10000, "Steve":10000, "Adren":10000}
```

After doing this, as you know, you need to loop over the items in the dict.

```
for x in employeeDict:
    x = len(employeeDict)
    if x > 5:
        print employeeDict[x]
```

In the code above, your "x" will be the employee name. And as you know, to asign a value to a key in dict, you have to use `dict[key] = value`, so try to do it in the `if x > 5:` block statement. Im not trying to give you the full answer, but to push you in to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try and analyse it :

```
employees = {"John":10000, "Daren":10000, "Graham":10000}

for name in employees:
    if len(name) > 5:
        employees[name] += 1000 * len(name)
```

If you have to stick with the string values you can do this :

```
employees = {"John":"10000", "Daren":"10000", "Graham":"10000"}

for name in employees:
    if len(name) > 5:
        employees[name] = str(int(employees[name]) + 1000 * len(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what your looking for.

```
employeeDict = {"John":10000, "Daren":10000, "Graham":10000, "Steve":10000, "Adren":10000}
print "Before increase"
print employeeDict

for name, salary in employeeDict.items():
    if len(name) > 4:
        employeeDict[name] = salary + len(name) * 1000
print "After increase"
print employeeDict
```

You had a few problems in your version.

- Your idention for your for-loop was not correct
- You were getting the length of the dictionary and not the length of the keys **in** the dictionary.
- You should make the values in your dictionary floats/integers.

Also note, I believe your homework said if the name was **longer than four characters**. So i used 4 instead of five.

Comment: You should add the salary increase to the current salary.

Comment: @LoganByers ah! your correct. I forgot that. Will update.

Comment: Thank you very much, only just started coding so have been struggling a little bit. This helped a lot!

Comment: @AlexChase thanks! If this helped, consider upvoting it, or marking it as selected.